# Not understanding the use of improper uniform prior on all positive integers

Tags: combinatorics, bayesian

I am reading Höhle & Held's paper, "Bayesian Estimation of the Size of a Population" (https://epub.ub.uni-muenchen.de/2094/1/paper_499.pdf) which discusses the well-known problem consisting in estimating the unknown size $N$ of a population whose individuals are numbered from $1$ to $N$, given the maximum number $x$ observed on a sample of size $n$.
It’s known that, knowing $N$, the probability of observing $x$ as the maximum is (their **formula $1$**):
$$P(x|N)=\frac{ \begin{pmatrix}x-1\\n-1\end{pmatrix} }{ \begin{pmatrix}N\\n\end{pmatrix} }, \quad n \leq x \leq N$$
Assuming a prior distribution $P(N)$ for $N$, the authors then write as follows the posterior distribution of $N$ (their **formula $3$**):
$$P(N|x)= \frac{P(x|N)P(N)}{ \sum_{N’=x}^\infty {P(x|N’)P(N’)} }$$
That is to say, they simply use the Bayes’ theorem. So far so good.

Where it gets stuck is when they choose for prior of $N$ an improper uniform prior on all positive integers, which they write $P(N) \propto 1$, for $N=0,...,\infty$, which is obviously not a probability distribution.
They then deduce (verbatim): “under the assumption of an improper uniform prior, the posterior distribution ($3)$ **simplifies to** (now their **formula $7$**):”
$$P(N|x)=\frac{ {\begin{pmatrix}N\\n\end{pmatrix}}^{-1} }{ \sum_{N’=x}^\infty {\begin{pmatrix}N'\\n\end{pmatrix}}^{-1} }$$
But I don't understand at all how it “**simplifies to**”... In order to go from **formula $3$** to **formula $7$**, it looks like they took $P(N)=P(N’)=\frac{1}{\begin{pmatrix}x-1\\n-1\end{pmatrix}}$, which is not possible…
As their writing of **$(7)$** seems to flow from the writing of **$(3)$**, it is that I did not understand anything about how to concretely use a prior for $N$ which is an improper uniform prior on all positive integers...
Could you make me explicit how it's possible to go from **formula $3$** to **formula $7$**?

Comment: Check your algebra. If you take formula (3), and replace $P(x|N)$ in the numerator with $\binom {x-1}{n-1}\binom Nn$, and replace $P(x|N')$ in the denominator with $\binom{x-1}{n-1}\binom{N'}n$, then the $\binom{x-1}{n-1}$'s in the numerator and denominator cancel each other, and all that remains is exactly their formula (7).

Comment: Well, yes, but, as far as I understand, all that remains is $$P(N|x)=\frac{ {\begin{pmatrix}N\\n\end{pmatrix}}^{-1} P(N)}{ \sum_{N’=x}^\infty {\begin{pmatrix}N'\\n\end{pmatrix}}^{-1} P(N')}$$.

Comment: Remember, they assumed the improper prior that $P(N) \propto 1$, which means that there exists $C$ such that $P(N)=C$ for all $N$. Making that replacement, the $C$'s in the numerator and denominator cancel.